# Pairwise comparison of interactions (factor*numerical variable)

Tags: interaction, paired-comparisons, lsmeans

--- Edit ---

Let's take a very simple model, with Y and X numerical variables and Fact a categorical variable.

```
mod = lm(Y~X*Fact)
```

I want to:

1. Check whether there are differences of Y between the Fact categories; i.e. to make pairwise comparisons of means of Y for Fact categories :

This can be easily done with the glht package :

```
 summary(glht(mod, mcp(Fact ="Tukey")))
```

2. And whether the slopes of y=f(x) are different for each value of Fact; again with pairwise comparisons. This is what I cannot find.

I found many discussions about glht or lsmeans here and elsewhere ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190986/post-hoc-tests-in-mixed-model-using-lsmeans-and-glht))([2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152397/interpreting-glm-interaction-contrasts-in-r-using-glht))([3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145765/post-hoc-testing-in-multcompglht-for-mixed-effects-models-lme4-with-interact))([4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/multcomp-examples.pdf)) but they are all about interactions between two factors, not numerical variable*factor, so I wonder if I might have missed something obvious there?

Comment: Your rephrased question (1) is still somewhat misleading, in that this comparison is ambiguous because it depends on `X`. I think `glht` uses the mean of `X` but am not sure. At any rate, it is extremely important to state which `X` is being used; otherwise, we're not giving the complete story. The code in my answer shows how to do this for 3 different `X` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the implications of the model you fitted. Since `X` is a quantitative predictor and `Fact` is a factor, your model has fitted 3 straight lines having different slopes and intercepts. It's almost the same as separately fitting the 3 lines with the data split according to `Fact`, except that they share common variance estimates.

Given this, what do you mean by "differences of Y between Fact categories"? The factor levels compare differently at each `X` value, for which there are potentially infinitely many. If you want to do these comparisons at particular `X` values, it is easy enough:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(mod, pairwise ~ Fact | X, at = list(X = c(-2, 0, 2))
```

(but substitute the particular `X` values of interest)

I completely don't understand the second question about whether the interactions are significantly different. Perhaps you want to compare the slopes of the three fitted lines? That can be done using

```
lstrends(mod, pairwise ~ Fact, var = "X")
```